# Get image Width after resizing Height

Tags: javascript

I have an image :

```
img {
  position : absolute;
  transition : 1s;
}
```

I zoom on a specific part of this image by changing his height and using *style.left*

```
    img.style.height = "100%";

    var width = img.clientWidth;
    img.style.left = width+"px";
```

The problem is that the 1s transition make the clientWidth false because the final width is achieve after the transition finish. I don't want to pause the program for 1s but **I want to get the final width of the image after the 1s of height transition.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's basically maintaining the aspect ratio of the image, so to know the width after the transition, we calculate it.

The Formula is [ref](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180804/how-to-get-the-aspect-ratio-of-an-image):

> **user-chosen height * original width / original height**

```js
document.querySelector("img").onclick = e => {

  let originalImgBounds = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  let newZoomedHeight = 300;

  let newZoomedWidth = newZoomedHeight * originalImgBounds.width / originalImgBounds.height;

  e.target.style.height = newZoomedHeight + "px";
  e.target.style.left = newZoomedWidth + "px";

};
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  left: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timeout of 1 second and then execute your code:
Here's some [doc](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

```
 setTimeout(function(){ 
    img.style.height = "100%";
    var width = img.clientWidth;
    img.style.left = width+"px";
 }, 1000);
```

Comment: I prefer to avoid this solution, _I don't want to pause the program for 1s_

Comment: @Poulpynator Do a `setTimeout(fn, 0)` then

Comment: The problem if I do this is that I will have 1s of transition for height and 1s of another transition for width

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has an eventlistener for transitions (and animations). The snippet below fetches the correct transitionEvent (for cross-browser) and applies it to the element. You can then bind a function to the transition event.

Source: [Detect the End of CSS Animations and Transitions with Javascript](https://jonsuh.com/blog/detect-the-end-of-css-animations-and-transitions-with-javascript/)

```js
var image = document.querySelector("img"),
    transitionEvent = whichTransitionEvent();


image.addEventListener("click", function() {
  image.style.height = "300px";
  image.addEventListener(transitionEvent, customFunction);
});

function customFunction(event) {
  var width = image.clientWidth;
  image.style.left = width+"px";
  image.removeEventListener(transitionEvent, customFunction);
}

function whichTransitionEvent(){
  var t,
      el = document.createElement("fakeelement");

  var transitions = {
    "transition"      : "transitionend",
    "OTransition"     : "oTransitionEnd",
    "MozTransition"   : "transitionend",
    "WebkitTransition": "webkitTransitionEnd"
  }

  for (t in transitions){
    if (el.style[t] !== undefined){
      return transitions[t];
    }
  }
}
```

```css
img {
  position:absolute;
  height: 200px;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" />
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to cut the animation into two step, it's why I don't want to use timeout.The width and the height are modify at the same time.